# MVC and MVVM architecture implementation for android

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

Please can anyone share a simple example of the two application architectures in android. It will be great if they implement the same functionality using the two approaches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi the following are the examples of mvvm(presentation model) in Android - [Album Sample](https://github.com/RoboBinding/RoboBinding/tree/develop/album-sample), which is an android translation of Martin Fowler's original album example, and [AndroidMVVM](https://github.com/RoboBinding/AndroidMVVM), a minimal demo app. But I don't have a MVC example, hopefully someone else can offer it.

Comment: Thanks Cheng, will wait for some more answers.